# Поиск элементов в QGridLayout

Tags: c++, qt, поиск, grid, qwidget

У меня есть `QGridLayout`, он находится в `ScrollArea` и заполнен кнопками с картинками (689 кнопок). Я хочу сделать поиск элементов в нём. Есть массив `items`, который хранит названия всех картинок. Я решил сделать так - каждый раз, когда пользователь вводит символ - идёт проверка по этому массиву, потом все старые кнопки удаляются и отображаются только те, названия картинок на которых, содержат введённые символы. Например, если пользователь вводит "*ко*" будут отображены все кнопки, которые содержат картинки, имеющие "*ко*" в названии. Но тот вариант, который я реализовал работает слишком медленно (и вообще, мне кажется, что это какой-то костыль).

Вот, что я сделал:

```
void findElements(Ui::MainWindow * ui, QVector<QPushButton*> &btnVector, QString text){
    QIcon icon;

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < btnVector.length(); i++) if (btnVector[i] != nullptr) delete btnVector[i];

    int counter = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 689; ++i){
        if (items[i].toLower().contains(text.toLower()) || text == "") {
            counter++;
            icon = QIcon("images/" + items[i]);
            btnVector[i] = new QPushButton("");
            btnVector[i]->setIcon(icon);
            btnVector[i]->setIconSize(QSize (100, 100));
            btnVector[i]->setFixedSize(QSize (150, 150));
            ui->gridLayout->addWidget(btnVector[i], (int) ((counter-1) / 5), (counter-1) % 5);
        }
        else btnVector[i] = nullptr;
    }
}
```

Здесь удаляются все кнопки, потом проверяется текст на соответствие названиям, если соответствие найдено - создаётся кнопка, иначе - соответствующему элементу вектора присваивается `nuulprt`. Также в начале функции - проверка на `nullptr`, чтобы программа не вылетела при попытке удалить `nullptr`. Как я уже говорил - это вариант не очень. Также, если будет введён текст, который не соответствует - весь вектор заполнится `nullptr` и останутся висеть кнопки, которые последние соответствовали одному из условий.

---

Есть ещё один вариант - он работает быстро (и, мне кажется именно его нужно доработать и использовать).

```
void findElements(QVector<QPushButton*> &btnVector, QString text){

        foreach (QPushButton* btn, btnVector) btn->hide();

        for (int i = 0, counter = 0; i < 689; ++i){
            if (items[i].toLower().contains(text.toLower()) || text == "") {
                btnVector[i]->show();
            }
        }
}
```

Но в нём кнопки располагаются неправильно, он кнопки не перемещает, а только прячет лишние. Поэтому может быть - одна кнопка слева, другая справа, потом несколько пустых строк и ещё одна в центре. Я не знаю как сделать, чтобы они размещались правильно.

Как это можно реализовать, чтобы поиск работал быстро (чтобы его можно было использовать не по нажатию на кнопку, а каждый раз, когда пользователь что-то вводит)?

Comment: 689 кнопок - ИМХО лучше уж написать CLI интерфейс

Comment: `чтобы программа не вылетела при попытке удалить nullptr` - вызов оператора `delete` для `nullptr` к проблемам не приведет.

Comment: Может лучше использовать QTableView? Там поиск можно реализовать через model-view

Comment: @e.n.shirokov спасибо, попробую сделать